# Hershey Park Kettle Corn kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

After a camp trip to Hershey Park, there was some confusion as to the kashrus of Kettle Corn Popcorn -  it is apparently certified under the "Buggy K" by Rabbi Shaya Sackett, Rav of Degel Israel, an OU shul in Lancaster, PA. Any ideas as to the kashrus of the popcorn?

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you expect in the way of an answer. According to the website of SweetandSalty Snacks.com all products made, sold & served at the Hershey Park Kettle Korn concession are certified kosher/parve. http://sweetnsaltysnacks.com/#kosher

Comment: According to the Kosherquest.org web site, the Buggy K supervision is reliable. http://kosherquest.org/kosher-symbols/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vaad of Lancaster
Cong. Degel Israel
1120 Columbia Avenue
Lancaster, PA 17603
(717) 397 0183
Rabbi Shaya Sackett

I checked with the Star-K in Baltimore (410-484-4110) this morning (Erev Shavuos 5777) and they said that the product (Kettle Corn Popcorn) is fine and verified the Hechsher certification.

I also found at [KosherQuest.org](http://kosherquest.org/kosher-symbols/)

> These Kosher Symbols are approved by Rabbi Eidlitz and the Kosher
>   Information Bureau.

[Vaad of Tidewater Virginia](http://www.vaadoftidewater.com/kosher/kosher-symbols/) also lists this as an *approved* kosher symbol

[BaDatz of Canada](http://www.badatz.ca/unitedstates) also lists this as a *reliable* hechsher.

Comment: @sabbahillel Rabbi Sackett received semicha from Ner Yisroel. http://lancasteronline.com/lancaster/news/meet-shaya-sackett-spiritual-leader-of-lancaster-s-degel-israel/article_b4463842-4b22-11e4-b3e4-001a4bcf6878.html

Comment: @YaacovDeane While that my be an indication, it is better to check the actual hechsher rather than where he received semicha.

Comment: @sabbahillel Not disagreeing. I also listed the KosherQuest.org reference in my comment to the OP. But some people may prefer more independent references that Star-K, like you also listing BaDatz of Canada. Star-K is strongly affiliated with Ner Yisroel via Rav Heinemann.